# Is there a reason to activate an account after registration?

Tags: workflow, user-accounts

my question is about the workflow of a web registration.

1) register with email + basic data

2) activate the account with a special secret link <- is this necessary?

3) allow the user to log in to the system

EDIT: I want to make the process as simple as possible without a password to choose/remember.

In more detail:
After a user is registering on a web site I sent out a confirmation with a generated password to login on the site and proceed.

Many sites sent an activation link first and then allow logging in to the system.

Is there any reason to do this additional step when I generate the password and sent it out to the user?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the activation link is to guarentee that the email address provided by the user is one to which they have access. If you are generating a password and sending it via email to the user's email address, then the link is not required (because them logging in means that they read your email).

However, email is generally not a secure way to distribute information over the internet. You are sending them the password in plaintext, and you do not know how many people have access to that email account (e.g. a shared family account). I think you would be better off allowing the user to choose their own password at registration and then send them a link (offer to generate a password for them on the registration page, if you really believe that generating it is better).

Comment: In the end I could also send out a special link containing the "password" and log them in automatically. What do you think?

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any reason to do this additional step when I generate the password and sent it out to the user?

To ensure that the provided email address exists, and belongs to the person who registered the account.

---

I've noticed an increasing number of websites which skip this step. It seems to be a trend.

Answer (score 0):

The validation of an email account is usually to help prevent someone creating numerous accounts. This helps prevents spammers and various other bad people from attacking your site from different accounts.

In general you're trying to ensure that the person is who they say they are and that you have an outside means of communicating with them.

Answer (score 0):

1 - to ensure that the email is belong to the registerd user.
2 - to make it harder to the people want to create many accounts (like forums where a single person have so many accounts to use them in voting or somthing).
I remembered a funny site that gives you a [10 minutes email](http://10minutemail.com/10MinuteMail/index.html) , just to skip the process of creating a new email or even spamming your email by the sites you've registered in.

Answer (score 0):

This way you make sure that the email address is valid and it will be more difficult for a spider to generate many users than without this step. Also, you might do a lot of things in your database when a user is registered and you can do these after the user is validated, to save time by not creating extra traffic on your database server for fake users.